# Ошибка "В экземпляре объекта не задана ссылка на объект."

Tags: c#, .net

Есть такая структура:

```
public struct Points
    {
        public int[] Height;
        public int[] Width;
        public int[] OldWidth;
    }
```

...........

```
        Points[] poi = {
    new Points { Width = new int[1] { Width } , Height = new int[1] { Height }, OldWidth = new int[1] {Width} 
      } 
  };
```

Заполняю её как массив. Как потом обратиться к свойствам структуры `Points`?

Пытаюсь так:

```
            for (int k = 0; k <= poi.Length; k++)
            {
                for (var y = 0; y < poi[k].Height[0]; y++)
                {
                    for (var x = poi[k].OldWidth[0]; x < poi[0].Width[0]; x++)
                    {
                        //result.SetPixel(x, y, img.GetPixel(x + left.X, y + left.Y));
                        if (img.GetPixel(x, y).R == 0)
                            a++;

                    }
                }
            }
```

Ошибка: {"В экземпляре объекта не задана ссылка на объект."}

Answer (score 1):

`k <= poi.Length` - вот ошибка. Нужно `k < poi.Length`, т.к. нумерация элементов идёт с нуля, соответственно длина массива всегда на 1 больше, чем максимальный индекс элемента.

Кстати, такая ошибка легко ловится при отладке, так что дэбагить, дэбагить и ещё раз дэбагить, товарищи!

Comment: Не, непомогло, эта ошибка появляется даже, если попытаться обратиться так: 

    MessageBox.Show(poi[0].pHeight.Length.ToString());

А если так:

    MessageBox.Show(poi[0].Length.ToString());

то никакой ошибки нет.

Comment: могу показатся нубом, но что это за запись?

``Width = new int[1] { Width }``

почему не просто:

``Width = new int[1]``